# A java map where the keys are known however the values should be computed later on as they are expensive

Tags: java, caching

Does a java map implementation exist where the keys are known, however the values should only be computed on the first access as calculating the values is expensive.

The following demonstrates how I would like it to work.

```
someMap.keySet(); // Returns all keys but no values are computed.
someMap.get(key); // Returns the value for key computing it if needed.
```

The reason for this is I have something which holds a bunch of data and this Object returns the data as a `Map<String, String>` this is computationally heavy to compute because computing the values is expensive, the keys are however cheap to compute.

The Map must maintain its type so I can't return a `Map<String, Supplier<String>>`. The returned `Map` may be returned as read only.

The map itself could be created by passing in both a `Set<String>` defining the keys and a `Function<String, String>` which given a key returns its value.

Comment: Do you want to cache the calculated values in the map?

Comment: Yeah I think that is a good idea, and I ended up doing that.

Comment: Guava has a `LoadingCache` interface which does precisely this.

Comment: Does it let you iterate over the keys without having values in the cache? And can it look like  map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to have a Map that takes a `Set` of keys and a `Function` which given a key can compute the value.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

/**
 * Create a Map where we already know the keys but computing the values is expensive and so is delayed as 
 * much as possible. 
 *
 */
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MapWithValuesProvidedByFunction implements Map<String, String> {

    /**
     * All keys that are defined.
     */
    private Set<String> keys;

    /**
     * A function which maps a key to its value.
     */
    private Function<String, String> mappingFunction;

    /**
     * Holds all keys and values we have already computed.
     */
    private final Map<String, String> computedValues = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return keys.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return keys.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return keys.contains(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        if(computedValues.size() == keys.size()) return computedValues.containsValue(value);
        for(String k : keys) {
            String v = get(k);
            if(v == value) return true;
            if(v != null && v.equals(value)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String get(Object key) {
        if(keys.contains(key)) {
            return computedValues.computeIfAbsent(key.toString(), mappingFunction);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String put(String key, String value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not modifiable");
    }

    @Override
    public String remove(Object key) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not modifiable");
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends String> m) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not modifiable");
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not modifiable");
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> keySet() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(keys);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> values() {
        return keys.stream().map(this::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>> entrySet() {
        Set<Entry<String, String>> set = new HashSet<>();
        for(String s : keys) {
            set.add(new MyEntry(s, this::get));
        }
        return set;
    }

    @AllArgsConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    public class MyEntry implements Entry<String, String> {
        private String key;
        private Function<String, String> valueSupplier;

        @Override
        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        @Override
        public String getValue() {
            return valueSupplier.apply(key);
        }

        @Override
        public String setValue(String value) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not modifiable");
        }
    }

}
```

An example of this being used might be:

```
Map<String, String> map = new MapWithValuesProvidedByFunction(
    Set.of("a", "b", "c"), // The known keys
    k -> "Slow to compute function"); // The function to make the values
```

Changing this to be generic should be easy enough.

I suspect a better solution exists, however this might be good enough for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.  The map has a key and a Fnc class which holds a function and the argument to the function.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class MapDemo {

    public static Map<String, Object> mymap = new HashMap<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapDemo thisClass = new MapDemo();

    // populate the functions   
        mymap.put("v1", new Fnc<String>(String::toUpperCase));

        mymap.put("10Fact", new Fnc<Integer>((Integer a) -> {
            int f = 1;
            int k = a;
            while (k-- > 1) {
                f *= k;
            }
            return f + "";
        }));


        mymap.put("expensive", 
                new Fnc<Integer>(thisClass::expensiveFunction));

        // access them - first time does the computation
        System.out.println(getValue("expensive", 1000));
        System.out.println(getValue("10Fact", 10));
        System.out.println(getValue("v1", "hello"));

        // second time does not.
        System.out.println(getValue("expensive"));
        System.out.println(getValue("10Fact"));
        System.out.println(getValue("v1"));

    }



    public String expensiveFunction(int q) {
        return q * 100 + ""; // example
    }

    static class Fnc<T> {
        Function<T, String> fnc;
        public Fnc(Function<T,String> fnc) {
            this.fnc = fnc;
        }

    }


    public <T> void addFunction(String key,
            Function<String, T> fnc) {
        mymap.put(key, fnc);
    }

    public static String getValue(String key) {
        Object ret = mymap.get(key);
        if (ret instanceof Fnc) {
            return null;
        }
        return (String)mymap.get(key);
    }

    public static <T> String getValue(String key, T arg) {
        Object ret = mymap.get(key);

        if (ret instanceof Fnc) {
            System.out.println("Calculating...");
            ret = ((Fnc)ret).fnc.apply(arg);
            mymap.put(key, ret);
        }
        return (String) ret;

    }
}
```

First time thru, the function is called and the value is computed, stored, and returned.  Subsequent calls return the stored value.

Note that the value replaces the computing function.

Comment: That is ok, but it doesn't really give a typedmap back but it is nice that you can have different functions depending on key.

Comment: Please explain.  The map is typed and takes a function.  And doesn't compute the value until you need it.  You can get all the keys if required.  The function is replaced with the value the first time it is called.  And I don't understand why it was downvoted since it works as advertised.

Comment: Your Map is `Map<String, Object>` and is not a wanted `Map<String, String>` being able to have this work `String s = map.get(k)` is required.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with standard Java.  You can do something like `map.compute(..)` but that would mean passing the function each time you want to get the value which also doesn't meet your requirement.  You could implement your own version of a `map` but it wouldn't be standard.